# MSBuild 2015 fails packaging web app from VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, msdeploy

I have a build server that until recently had up to .Net 4.5.1 and VS2010/VS2012 installed. I ran MSBuild to build and package web apps as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" Hartford.Pace.sln /nologo /v:n /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:EnableNuGetPackageRestore=True
```

I recently updated the build server to include Frameworks through 4.6.1 and VS2013/VS2015. Everything was installed in sequence. I updated the build command to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" Hartford.Pace.sln /nologo /v:n /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:EnableNuGetPackageRestore=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0
```

And now I'm getting the following error only for VS2010 web apps:

```
"d:\a5\bi_hartsource_pace\Microsoft_Build_Web_App\trunk\Hartford.Pace.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"d:\a5\bi_hartsource_pace\Microsoft_Build_Web_App\trunk\Hartford.Pace.Services\Hartford.Pace.Services.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(PackageUsingManifest target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009,5): error : Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:.) [d:\a5\bi_hartsource_pace\Microsoft_Build_Web_App\trunk\Hartford.Pace.Services\Hartford.Pace.Services.csproj]
```

Which points to a problem with the packaging target files. I checked them and none of them were changed by the update.

1. Does anyone know of side-by-side issues with VS2010 and VS2015? I'd like to upgrade the VS2010 Solutions but it's not my code and I need to build existing apps without modification.
2. Is this the best method for packaging an app without having the developers create publishing profiles or running anything at their end? This is supposed to be a fully automated build and deploy process. It has been working for three years with no issues but I'm open to suggestions that I can implement entirely on my build server without involving changing files in the source code (including csproj or other controlling files).

Answer (score 0):

Add `/p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0`

Comment: Do you have VS installed on the build server?  Also try setting the version to 14.0.

Comment: I have VS2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015 installed on the server. I'll try spoofing it to 14.0 even though the Solution is a VS2010 Solution

Comment: I know we can get this working.  We updated from TFS 2010 to 2015 last year and have very few problems.  But it all worked out.  The only projects we had to change were our CodedUI projects.